# Representing a number without the zero coefficients

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n = a_0k^s+a_1k^{s-1}+\cdots+a_s$, a representation of any integer $n$ in base $k>0$.

In George E.A's Number Theory it is stated that

> It is possible that some of the coefficient $a_i$ in a particular representation of $n$ are equal to zero. Without affecting the representation, we may exclude the terms that are $0$.

Then it states that excluding the zero terms, $n$ may be represented as $n=a_0k^s+a_1k^{s-1}+\cdots+a_{s-t}k^t$

say $n=101$ and that we are working in base $10$. I dont get how $n$ could be expressed that way. Supressing the $0$ terms give
$$n=1(10)^2+1(10)^0$$

It seems that there is no way to express $n$ as a sum of coefficient such that the powers are decreasing with step $1$, such that $n$ would be equal to $a_110^s+a_210^{s-1}$  where $a_1$,$a_2$ are greater than zero.

Is $n=a_0k^s+a_1k^{s-1}+\cdots+a_{s-t}k^t$ really a valid way to express any integer with the $0$ terms supressed ? If so, what is the wrong assumption that I am making ?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe only the trailing zeroes are excluded.

Comment: Whether it is OK to exclude terms depends on context. Obviously in a context where there is a rigid requirement that each coefficient be $1/10$ the previous coefficient (as i the coefficients of the digits $1,2,0,4$ when I write the integer $1204$ in decimal notation), it is **not** OK to exclude zero terms. But in another context, you might just be manipulating $a_0k^s+a_1k^{s-1}+\cdots+a_{s-t}k^t$ as a generic formula in which the coefficients might as well be (almost) anything. And then it is OK if they're not in strict geometric progression.

Comment: This is one of those things that you read in a math textbook where it doesn't pay to stare at it too long by itself. Read ahead a bit. What are they going to do with this "representation" with the zero terms removed? Then it may be clearer why it's OK to remove the terms, and why you would **want** to remove them.

Comment: @Karl Yes, this is it. thank you

Comment: @DavidK thanks for your advice !